# vscode intellisense node.js works for .js files - not .ts files

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Unable to get intellisense to work for .ts files.

**test.js**

```
var http = require('http');
http.[intellisense available]
```

**test.ts**

```
var http = require('http');
http.[no suggestions]
```

Does not appear to be reading index.d.ts

Here is ***tsconfig.json***:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "watch": true
  }
}
```

Any suggestions.  Really want to use typescript, but need the hints while learning node.  Prefer not to use javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: make sure you have TypeScript compiler installed by `npm install -g typescript`

Comment: [This](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_tsconfigjson) could help

Answer (score 8):

Learning curve.

For a .js file:

```
var http = require('http');
```

for a .ts file:

```
import http = require('http');
```

The transpiler will write out: var http = ...

The "import" instead of "var" gets intellisense to work. Right clicking for "go to definition" works.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code's JavaScript and TypeScript intellisense for Node and third party modules is powered by typings files (`d.ts` files).

In JavaScript code, we [automatically](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition) download these typings because they are only used for tooling support. When we see `require('http')` in a js file for example, we'll automatically install the node typings. That's why get the suggestions in that case

In TypeScript code, the typings files must be manually managed because they are part of the compile process. To install the node typings for example, just run `npm install --save-dev @types/node`. Here's more info about `@types`: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

I suspect you just need to install the node typings to get proper intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

For me, what worked was not OP's answer, but this code below:

```
import * as http from "http";
```